# Mysql ordering by records that exist in joined table first

Tags: mysql, join

I am looking for a way to join 2 tables but make the results that have records in both tables appear first in ordering.

Explanation:

```
SELECT npcdef.name,npcdef.id, npcinfo.npcid 
from npcdef 
LEFT JOIN npcinfo ON npcinfo.npcid=npcdef.id 
WHERE npcdef.name LIKE '%$npcname%';
```

How can I order the results so the records that exist in npcinfo appear first, I imagine it would be some ORDER BY statement but unsure of the logic.

Thanks

Comment: The query will only return records that appear in both tables, so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that I have amended it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY npcinfo.npcid IS NULL
```

For rows that are in `npcinfo`, `npcid` will not be `NULL`, so `npcinfo.npcid IS NULL` will be `false`, which is `0`. For rows that are not in `npcinfo`, `npcid` will be `NULL`, so this expression will be `true`, which is `1`.